# batch procedure, when to commit transactions?

Tags: sql, oracle, transactions, plsql

I'm pretty new to PL-SQL although I've got lots of db experience with other RDBMS's. Here's my current issue.

```
procedure CreateWorkUnit
is
update workunit 
set workunitstatus = 2 --workunit loaded 

where
    SYSDATE between START_DATE and END_DATE
and workunitstatus = 1 --workunit created;

--commit here?

call loader; --loads records based on status, will have a commit of its own

update workunit wu
set workunititemcount = (select count(*) from workunititems wui where wui.wuid = wu.wuid)
where workunitstatus = 2
```

So the behaviour I'm  seeing, with or without commit statements is that I have to execute twice. Once to flip the statuses, then the loader will run on the second execution. I'd like it all to run in one go.

I'd appreciate any words of oracle wisdom.

Thanks!

Comment: So your problem lies in the code you haven't shown us, the LOADER itself. For some reason it's not picking up the change in work status. There are any number of reasons why that might be, and without sight of the code it's hard to make suggestions.

Comment: So what exactly does "*call loader*" do?

Comment: Apart from the missing `loader`, (a) your `procedure CreateWorkUnit` code fragment is unclear: is it within an anonymous block, or is it preceded by a `CREATE` command? (b) How do you know that `CreateWorkUnit` is executed at all? (c) it is missing an `END`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When to commit transactions in a batch procedure?  It is  a good question, although it only seems vaguely related to the problems with the code you post.  But let's answer it anyway.

We need to commit when the PL/SQL procedure has completed a unit of work.  A unit of work is a business transaction.  This would normally be at the end of the program, the last statement before the EXCEPTION section.

Sometimes not even then. The decision to commit or rollback properly lies with the top of the calling stack.  If our PL/SQL is being called from a client (may a user clicking a button on a screen) then perhaps the client should issue the commit.

But it is not unreasonable for a batch process to manage its own commit (and rollback in the case of errors).  But the main point is that the only the toppermost procedure should issue COMMIT.  If a procedure calls other procedures those called programs should not issue commits or rollbacks.   If they should handle any errors (log etc) and re-raise them to the calling program.  Let it decode whether to rollback.  Because all the called procedures run in the same session and hence the same transaction: a rollback in a called program will revert all the changes in the batch process.  That's not right.  The same reasoning applies to commits.

You will sometimes read advice on using intermittent commits to break up long running processes into smaller units e.g. every 1000 inserts.  This is bad advice for several reasons, not all of them related to transactions.  The pertinent ones are:

1. Issuing a commit frees locks on resources.  This is the cause of `ORA-1555 Snapshot too old` errors.
2. It also affects read consistency, which only applies at the statement and/or transaction level.  This is the cause of `ORA-1002 Fetch out of sequence` errors.
3. It affects re-startability.  If the program fails having processed 30% of the records, can we be confident it will only process the remaining 70% when we re-run the batch?
4. Once we commit records other sessions can see those changes: does it make sense for other users to see a partially changed view of the data?

So, the words of "Oracle wisdom" are: always align the database transaction with the business transaction, with a single commit per unit of work.

---

Somebody mentioned [autonmous transactions](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/appdev.920/a96624/13_elems3.htm#32734) as a way of issuing commits in sub-processes.  This is usually a bad idea.  Changes made in an autonomous transaction are visible to other sessions but not to our own.  That very rarely makes sense.  It also creates the same problems with re-startability which I discussed earlier.

The only acceptable use for automomous transactions is recording activity (error log, trace, audit records).  We need that data to persist regardless of what happens in the wider transaction.  Any other use of the pragma is almost certainly a workaround for a porr design, which actually just makes the problem worse.

Comment: thanks a ton for the volunteer info here. All of my background is mssql and my current shop is an oracle customer. Gladly, I can write to sql standards and I'm still efficient, but I have to get used to writing cursors... they're easier on the temp space :)

Answer (score 0):

You may not need to commit in pl/sql procedure. the procedures that you call inside another procedure will use same session so you don't need to commit. by the way procedure must completely rollback if it session rollbacked or has an exception.

Comment: You *can* commit within pl/sql.

Comment: not only you can commit in a procedure, you can also make it autonomous which will prevent it from commiting the main transaction (the one calling it)

Comment: @BurhanAli - Of course we *can* commit in a PL/SQL program. The question is whether we should, and if so, where? A commit inside a called program is probably in the wrong place: the decision to commit or rollback properly lies with the top of the calling stack. There are occasions this need not be true, but they are pretty rare.

Comment: @ABCade - likewise, of course we can use autonmous transactions.  But should we?  Almost certainly not.  The only valid use for autonmous transaction is writing log or trace records.  Trying to solve any other problem with autonomous transactions just means now you've got two problems.

Comment: @APC I wasn't making any commentary on whether you should or not. I was just disputing the statement in the answer: "You may not to commit in pl/sql procedure."

Comment: @BurhanAli - I read that statement as a typo for "You may not need to commit".

Answer (score 0):

I mis-classfied my problem. I thought this was a transaction problem and really it was one of my flags not being set as expected.A number field was null when I was expecting 0.

Sorry for that.
Josh Robinson